# Boundary points of convergence of a given power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$ be a complex power series with radius of convergence $R=1$.

Let $A=A(f)\subseteq S^{1}$ be the set of points $z$ on the boundary such that $f(z)$ converges.

$A$ can either be the whole unit circle $C^{1}$, the empty set $\emptyset$, or some set between them.

Is there any special property that $A$ must satisfy as a set? That is, if we choose an arbitary set $A\subseteq S^{1}$, can it always be represented as $A=A(f)$ for some power series $f$? If not, then what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $A$ to be a representable set?

One can ask similar questions for other constructions:

Which sets $B\subseteq S^{1}$ could be represented as $B(f)=\{z\in C^{1}|f(z)\text{ converges absolutely} \}$?

Which sets $C\subseteq S^{1}$ could be represented as $C(f)=A(f)-B(f)=\{z\in C^{1}|f(z)\text{ converges conditionally} \}$?

Comment: It's better not to name the power series $f(z)$ because that looks like a function. (Also you have both $S^1$ and $C^1?$)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was referring to the unit circle $S^{1}$ in all cases.

Comment: Your second question has an easy answer: either $B = S^1$ or $B = \emptyset$. That is what absolute convergence means.